# Laravel request + for loop

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I'm trying to make object's of an incoming formrequest like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $totalProducts; $i++) { 
      $products[$i] = new product($request->title+$i,$request->description+$i,$request->price+$i,$request->number+$i,$request->total+$i);
     }
```

But when I for example `dd($request->title1);` I receive an output. But when I do `dd($request->title+$i)` or `dd($request->title.$i)` it's only showing the number.

How can I use `$i` with a `$request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$request->input('title'.$i)` instead.

The reason `dd($request->title.$i)` is not working is that it acts as if you are asking the `request` object to return the `title` then concatenate to the result the value of `$i`, and since there is no value for `title` in the `request` object, nothing is returned or empty space and concatenated to it the value of `$i`.